# How to persist all Jenkins data on an EBS volume in docker

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ebs

I have the [Docker official jenkins repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker) running on an Ubuntu instance. In that document, it suggests a way to create a volume as a way to isolate all Jenkins data file.

The EC2 instance has the root volume and a second volume at /dev/xsdf:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  10G  0 disk
```

IF have tried mounting that volume as /var/jenkins_home in Ubuntu, and then referencing it at run time:

```
docker run --restart=always -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v \
/home/ubuntu/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -w /var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

It runs fine, but I do not see any files on the host in `/var/jenkins_home`

Is there another(Correct) way to mount a EBS volume on the host and use it for the Jenkins data volume?

I would like to be able to backup it by taking a snapshot of the volume and allow the data to persist between restarts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly it seems like you just have your volume syntax backwards. Think of the syntax like so:

```
-v /path/to/host/directory:/path/to/directory/inside/container
```

So in your case `/var/jenkins_home` is the correct directory inside the container, but you'd need to be looking in `/home/ubuntu/jenkins_home` currently to see the data from the container.

Here's a working example on my laptop:

```
[10:46 PM]~/Desktop ➭ mkdir jenkins_test
[10:46 PM]~/Desktop ➭ cd jenkins_test/
[10:46 PM]~/Desktop/jenkins_test ➭ docker run --rm -it --name jenkins \
➭ -p 8080:8080 \
➭ -p 50000:50000 \
➭ -v /Users/jadametz/Desktop/jenkins_test:/var/jenkins_home \
➭ jenkins/jenkins:lts

...

[10:52 PM]~/Desktop/jenkins_test ➭ ls -lh
total 80
-rw-r--r--   1 jadametz  staff   1.6K Aug 28 22:48 config.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jadametz  staff   102B Aug 28 22:48 copy_reference_file.log
-rw-r--r--   1 jadametz  staff   159B Aug 28 22:48 hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml
-rw-------   1 jadametz  staff   1.7K Aug 28 22:48 identity.key.enc
drwxr-xr-x   3 jadametz  staff   102B Aug 28 22:48 init.groovy.d
-rw-r--r--   1 jadametz  staff    94B Aug 28 22:48 jenkins.CLI.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jadametz  staff   1.7K Aug 28 22:50 jenkins.install.InstallUtil.installingPlugins
-rw-r--r--   1 jadametz  staff     6B Aug 28 22:48 jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
drwxr-xr-x   2 jadametz  staff    68B Aug 28 22:48 jobs
drwxr-xr-x   3 jadametz  staff   102B Aug 28 22:48 logs
-rw-r--r--   1 jadametz  staff   907B Aug 28 22:48 nodeMonitors.xml
drwxr-xr-x   2 jadametz  staff    68B Aug 28 22:48 nodes
drwxr-xr-x  51 jadametz  staff   1.7K Aug 28 22:49 plugins
-rw-r--r--   1 jadametz  staff   129B Aug 28 22:50 queue.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 jadametz  staff    64B Aug 28 22:48 secret.key
-rw-r--r--   1 jadametz  staff     0B Aug 28 22:48 secret.key.not-so-secret
drwx------  11 jadametz  staff   374B Aug 28 22:48 secrets
drwxr-xr-x   5 jadametz  staff   170B Aug 28 22:48 updates
drwxr-xr-x   3 jadametz  staff   102B Aug 28 22:48 userContent
drwxr-xr-x   3 jadametz  staff   102B Aug 28 22:48 users
drwxr-xr-x  25 jadametz  staff   850B Aug 28 22:48 war
```

Comment: Thanks I reviewed and I believe my -v usage is correct. It is a host:container reference.  I this case the host path *is* `/home/ubuntu/jenkins`.

Comment: I see, so this issue is solved or you're still having trouble getting the content volumed out?